# AVFoundation Camera Check and Flip Variable

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera, avfoundation

I created a custom camera tool. Now, I am trying to  handle checking existence of cameras however, I only have Simulator (no camera) and iphone (both cameras). I handled no camera but I couldn't understand how it works for one camera, so I also couldn't figure out how to help the user flip the camera

Currently I am using following external library using [dojo custom camera](https://github.com/mcgraw/dojo-custom-camera)

Position `.Back` and `.Front` works, and I handled no camera, but I couldn't figure out how to

- handle checks for 1 camera
- assign a variable for the control of Back & Front cameras depending on their existence (So I can create a uibutton in the VC and control flipping of camera back and front).

---

```
// I call addVideoInput() while initializing

func addVideoInput() {
    if let device: AVCaptureDevice = self.deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front) {
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

func deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(mediaType: NSString, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition) -> AVCaptureDevice? {
    let devices: NSArray = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(mediaType as String)
    if devices.count != 0 {
        if var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice = devices.firstObject as? AVCaptureDevice {

            for device in devices {
                let d = device as! AVCaptureDevice
                if d.position == position {
                    captureDevice = d
                    break;
                }
            }
            print(captureDevice)
            return captureDevice
        }
    }
    print("doesnt have any camera")
    return nil

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to keep a pointer to both front and back camera ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'pointer'? I want to assign a variable to control the flip between front and back camera with a UIButton in the View. I can do that as I am initialising this class in my ViewController. For an example scenario, 'if user has 2 cameras - a variable knows that both Front & Back exists, and the display starts from Front initially, then uibutton flips to back camera in the first run and so on back and forth..'; 'else if user has only back camera, hide uibutton for flipping and show only back camera' - this kind of approach

Comment: a pointer = variable that points to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the object and create new object with use of few values and boolean uses.

Here I post the code for the when create the position of the camera `AVCaptureDevicePosition`.

In the top of the class add `enum`.

```
enum CameraType {
    case Front
    case Back
}
```

Initialise the variable.

```
var cameraCheck = CameraType.Back
```

Just change the following function.

```
func addVideoInput() {
        if cameraCheck ==  CameraType.Front  {
            cameraCheck = CameraType.Back
            let device: AVCaptureDevice = self.deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front)
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                    self.session.addInput(input)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }else{
            cameraCheck = CameraType.Front
            let device: AVCaptureDevice = self.deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back)
            do {
                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
                if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                    self.session.addInput(input)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }        
    }
```

Create one button into your `storyboard`.

Now into your `viewcontroller` create one `@IBAction` function.

```
@IBAction func changeCamera(){
        self.camera = nil

        self.initializeCamera()
        self.establishVideoPreviewArea()

        if isBackCamera == true {
           isBackCamera = false
            self.camera?.cameraCheck = CameraType.Front
        }else{
            isBackCamera = true
            self.camera?.cameraCheck = CameraType.Back
        }
    }
```

That's it your goal achieve.

[Also you can download the source code from here.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVigM97JuzCRU9fUXJZVGdzclU)

Answer (score 0):

Best to keep an enum IMO.

```
private enum CameraPosition {
    case Front, Back
}
```

Then when you press the button have

```
var currentState: CameraPostition
```

switch to the other camera position.

Then on the didSet of currentState config the camera

```
var currentState: CameraPostition {
    didSet {
       configCamera(state: currentState)
    }
}
```

EDIT: After some more information provided.

If you change

```
func addVideoInput() {
        let device: AVCaptureDevice = self.deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(AVMediaTypeVideo, position: AVCaptureDevicePosition.Back)
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

To

```
func addVideoInput(position: AVCaptureDevicePosition) {
        let device: AVCaptureDevice = self.deviceWithMediaTypeWithPosition(AVMediaTypeVideo, position: position)
        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            if self.session.canAddInput(input) {
                self.session.addInput(input)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Then when your "CurrentState" changes on the didSet of currentState you can just call the function.

```
func configCamera(state: CameraState) {
      switch state{
         case .Back:
              addVideoInput(.Back)
         case .Front
              addVideoInput(.Front)
      }
}
```

Comment: I got a bit lost implementing this. I am trying to tweak [XMCCamera.swift](https://github.com/mcgraw/dojo-custom-camera/tree/master/dojo-custom-camera), you would see both functions. Can you please guide me on implementing your approach? Because I couldn't figure out how to check if has either Front or Back camera either, because I don't have a device that has 1 camera.

Comment: Its more difficult as you need to be familiar with the parts of AVFoundation and it sounds like your using an example you found on github ?

Comment: Actually after hours of reading, I've found this example on github. I thought the best would be to go through it, understand it and tweak it. It's pretty small chunk of code. Now, I can take a photo and set it to UIImage, and present it now. The place I got stuck was just this bit, where I need to flip the camera depending on the number of cameras (and if there's only 1 camera, hide flip button). I'd be grateful if you can help me figure out this issue

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer however, I couldn't figure out how you did check if user has a camera or not. I mean what if the camera is nil or have only 1 camera. Can you please implement it on this github repo (it's only 2 files), so I understand how your enum setup works? I'd be very very grateful for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean variable isUsingFrontCamera, for the first time when the camera view loads,

Set,

```
isUsingFrontCamera = false;
```

Then on clicking on the camera switch button,

```
-(IBAction)switchCameras:(id)sender {
  AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition;
  if (isUsingFrontFacingCamera)
      desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
  else
      desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;

  for (AVCaptureDevice *d in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
      if ([d position] == desiredPosition) {
          [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] beginConfiguration];
          AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:d error:nil];
          for (AVCaptureInput *oldInput in [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] inputs]) {
              [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] removeInput:oldInput];
          }
          [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] addInput:input];
          [[captureVideoPreviewLayer session] commitConfiguration];
          break;
      }
  }
  isUsingFrontFacingCamera = !isUsingFrontFacingCamera;
}
```

Where captureVideoPreviewLayer is the,

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer
```

Also, you can get the count of your camera using

```
[[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count]
```

Then show and hide button accordingly

Comment: I don't know any Objective-C, can you please write it on Swift. I am trying to adapt [this code (XMCCamera.swift)](https://github.com/mcgraw/dojo-custom-camera/tree/master/dojo-custom-camera) to fit my scenario